# Ocelot gateway: No such host is known

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, consul, api-gateway, ocelot

I'm using Ocelot as gateway and Consul as Service Discovery.
I have an error after the first API call Ocelot Gateway in **Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]**

My output log is here:

```
Hosting environment: Development

Now listening on: http://localhost:50005
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50005/api/info
dbug: Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: ocelot pipeline started
dbug: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Upstream url path is /api/info
dbug: Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: downstream templates are /{url}
info: Ocelot.RateLimit.Middleware.ClientRateLimitMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: EndpointRateLimiting is not enabled for /{url}
info: Ocelot.Authentication.Middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: No authentication needed for /api/info
info: Ocelot.Authorisation.Middleware.AuthorisationMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: /{url} route does not require user to be authorised
dbug: Ocelot.DownstreamUrlCreator.Middleware.DownstreamUrlCreatorMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Downstream url is http://booking:50006/info
dbug: Ocelot.Requester.Middleware.HttpRequesterMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: IHttpRequester returned an error, setting pipeline error
warn: Ocelot.Requester.Middleware.HttpRequesterMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error making http request, exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
         at Ocelot.Requester.HttpClientHttpRequester.GetResponse(DownstreamContext context)
warn: Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnableToCompleteRequestError Message: Error making http request, exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
         at Ocelot.Requester.HttpClientHttpRequester.GetResponse(DownstreamContext context) errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/api/info, request method: GET
dbug: Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HLU1U83J55UD:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: ocelot pipeline finished
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 3008.734ms 500
```

The ocelot configuration is:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{url}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "ServiceName": "booking",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{url}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "ServiceDiscoveryProvider": {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 8500,
      "Type": "Consul"
    }
  }
}
```

In the first call, everything is right but after that suddenly I face the error.

Where is my problem?